# Increasing the icon size in android Launcher and All apps page

Tags: android, icons

I want to increase the app icon size in the Launcher and All apps page.We tried to set the android:rowHeight in GridView to 200dip in all_apps_2d.xml,but this doesnot have any affect in increasing the icon size.
    Can anyone help me in increasing the app icon size in a gridview.
Thanks,
Riyaz

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rather create a new icon of your desired size (i.e. 200*200 px). That will do it.

Comment: I tried what you suggested,it increases the icon size in emulator but not on the target. My target is a 800X480 touch screen display interfaced with imx53 ARD board.