# increasing the launcher icon size

Tags: android, launcher

How can i increase the size of launcher icons . I know that my custom launcher is taking images from the drawable-mdpi folder & the allowed icon size is 48x48 . I cant increase the size of launcher icon more than this.
Please help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223979/increasing-the-icon-size-in-android-launcher-and-all-apps-page

Comment: i saw that link . not much of a help

Answer (score 0):

the icon of luacher it prepered by system itself you just put in your resources the icons for each vervion and below the standard size for each version

LDPI - 36 x 36
MDPI - 48 x 48
HDPI - 72 x 72
XHDPI - 96 x 96
WEB - 512 x 512

Answer (score 0):

There was two way

```
1. Create your icon using 9-patch with your required size
2. Create different size of icon and put them in different drawable size. For this to know the size for specific like hdpi, mdpi etc just create sample/ open any exiting project which was created in juno(eclipse editor).
```

Here the specific size detail for different devices

```
ldpi-36x36
mdpi-48x48
hdpi-72x72
xdpi-96x96
web - 128x128
```

Comment: thanks for the reply . i have images of the size u said . can i increase its size like say my device uses mdpi images which are of size 48X48 i want to scale them to some size say 150x150 & then display . i tried scaling the bitmap but that dint help .

Comment: no you can't do this by programmatically for launcher icon for your application if you want to display in your application using ImageView/ImageButton then just set the size and set the scale type in that.

Comment: ok thanks . but i am not developing an application I am trying to edit the android launcher . so i tjaought it might be possible